# Tar command and PIPE

Tags: tar

Let say i want to :

Create a tar ball from a directory on  server A

Scp this tarball to a server B

Untar the in the server B

```
ssh root@serverB   " scp  root@serverA:/var/www/dirs.tar.gz  /var/www/dirs.tar.gz && tar -xvf  /var/www/dirs.tar.gz
```

I want to avoid repeating the path using a pipe. How to write it properly with a PIPE to get the second argument ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tarring a directory, copying it to a remote server, where it is untarred? Then `scp -r directory ...`, `rsync -r directory ...` or `sftp` are much better.

If you want to copy the tar file to the remote server and also unpack it, try

```
tar -cf - mydir | ssh root@192.168.1.248 'bash -c "tee archive.tar | tar -xf -"'
```

The `tee` is key here: It puts a copy of the tar file into the remote filesystem and passes the tarfile to the tar command, which unpacks it.

Perhaps a less convoluted solution is to simply `rsync` the directory to the remote server, where you create a tar file from it.

Answer (score 1):

We don't see how you create the tarball, and if that needs to be a separate step, but `tar` doesn't need to create/consume files, so something along these lines should work:

```
ssh serverA tar cz file… | tar xz
```

(for ease of understanding, I'm assuming you're already root@serverB and leaving out things like making sure you're in the right directory.)