# why does tee refuse to work when launched remotely via ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, tee

Where is my error? As an answer to a [Stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635472/tar-command-and-pipe), I tar a directory and transfer the archive to a remote system, where `tee` both deposits in a file and pipes it to `tar` for unpacking.

My original command is `tar -cf - mydir | ssh root@192.168.1.248 bash -c "tee archive.tar | tar -xf -"`. It creates `mydir`, but not `archive.tar`.

For a simpler test, I use `cat` to prove that I can write to remote `/tmp/outfile`, then overwrite `/tmp/outfile` with `tee`. However, `tee` doesn't seem to touch the file:

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.248 rm -r /tmp/outfile
$ echo data | ssh root@192.168.1.248 bash -cx "cat > /tmp/outfile"
+ cat
$ echo DATA | ssh root@192.168.1.248 bash -cx "tee /tmp/outfile"
DATA
+ tee
$ ssh root@192.168.1.248 cat /tmp/outfile
data
```

When `/tmp/outfile` doesn't exist, `tee` doesn't create it. **Why does `tee` not overwrite `/tmp/outfile` with DATA?** It does work as expected when log on to the remote server and run it there.

The remote server runs Centos 8. I have the nagging feeling that the error is obvious, but I just don't see it.

Comment: @icarus it won't

Comment: The ssh command already runs `bash -c` on any command you send it already so there's no need to add it yourself. That just adds an additional layer of quoting needed otherwise which is the problem you are running into.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classic quoting problem, except in this case you've clearly tried to address it. Consider your `tar` construct,

> ```
> ssh root@192.168.1.248 bash -c "tee archive.tar | tar -xf -"
> ```

The local shell will evaluate this as part of its normal processing, removing quotes, replacing variables, etc. The net result is that `ssh` will receive the command line for execution without the double quotes, and this is what's passed to the remote shell for execution

```
bash -c tee archive.tar | tar -xf -
```

The `bash` instance will assign `tee` as the argument parameter for `-c`, leaving `archive.tar` as a value passed in (and subsequently ignored) as `$0`. The `tee` command run under this `bash` instance has no output files listed so it simply pipes its content to *stdout* where it's captured and processed by `tar`.

The correct approach is to quote the command string passed to `ssh`, giving a command  like this

```
ssh root@192.168.1.248 'tee archive.tar | tar -xf -'
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had not taken into account that there won't be quotes when bash runs on the remote system. My solution is `tar -cf - mydir | ssh root@192.168.1.248 'bash -c "tee archive.tar | tar -xf -"'`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to involve an explicit invocation of bash on the remote side. You've already got a shell there (so `date | ssh 'cat >/tmp/file'` will work "as expected")

Comment: You do get a shell, but you don't know which as it's the login shell of that remote user. However, `tee archive.tar | tar -xf -` is portable shell code while @berndbausch's  `bash -c "tee archive.tar | tar -xf -"` is not as not all shells understand `"..."` as a quoting operator (not to mention that not all systems have the `bash` shell installed, and `bash` is a poor choice of shell to use over `ssh` as some  builds of `bash`, like on Debian read the `~/.bashrc`, even when not interactive like here when running over `ssh`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Are you sure about the 'not all shells understand `"..."` as a quoting operator'? As far as I know, at least sh, dash, bash, ksh, csh, tcsh know it.

Comment: @RolandIllig, `rc`, `es`, `akanga` don't.